# Carrot2 doesn't show clusters all containing specific word on search

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, clustered-index, carrot2

I selected some rows all containing specific word like `StackOverFlow` from my database and saved them in a text file. 
Then, i used Lucene to index the file contents.

When i try to search `StackOverFlow` on indexed files using Carrot2, it returns no document, But for other words that i know they are exist at least in one document, it returns some of them.

In Carrot2 document, there is an explanation about an attribute called [`Maximum word document frequency`](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.kmeans.TermDocumentMatrixBuilder.maxWordDf):

> Maximum word document frequency. The maximum document frequency
>   allowed for words as a fraction of all documents. Words with document
>   frequency larger than maxWordDf will be ignored. For example, when
>   maxWordDf is 0.4, words appearing in more than 40% of documents will
>   be be ignored. A value of 1.0 means that all words will be taken into
>   account, no matter in how many documents they appear.  This attribute
>   may be useful when certain words appear in most of the input documents
>   (e.g. company name from header or footer) and such words dominate the
>   cluster labels. In such case, setting maxWordDf to a value lower than
>   1.0, e.g. 0.9 may improve the clusters.
>
> Another useful application of this attribute is when there is a need
>   to generate only very specific clusters, i.e. clusters containing
>   small numbers of documents. This can be achieved by setting maxWordDf
>   to extremely low values, e.g. 0.1 or 0.05.

So, when i do set `maxWordDf` to 1.0, nothing changes and it still shows no document on search.

How do i resolve my problem?

Comment: If the search does not return documents, the problem happens before clustering, so clustering attributes are irrelevant here. A possible cause may be a mismatch between the Lucene analyzer used for indexing and then for searching in Carrot2. Carrot2 uses Lucene StandardAnalyzer by default (http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.LuceneDocumentSource.analyzer).

Comment: @StanislawOsinski I had been using Persian Analyzer before you mentioned to use StandardAnalyzer. Now, using StandardAnalyzer, it works fine. This may be a bug to consider.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason documents are missing in search results is usually a mismatch between the analyzer used to index documents and the analyzer used by Carrot2 during the search. By default, Carrot2 uses Lucene's `StandardAnalyzer`, you provide a different analyzer using the [LuceneDocumentSource.analyzer](http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.attribute.LuceneDocumentSource.analyzer) attribute.